# Is there a JavaScript function to do a animation in reverse after clicking a button a 2nd time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I'm still learning JavaScript, and not too familiar with it or I have just flat out forgotten it. But I have a button on my page that looks like this:

```js
function hiddenjs() {
     var x = document.getElementById("hiddenjs");
     if (x.style.display === "block") {
          x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "block";
     }
   }
```

```css
   .hiddenjsa {
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: red;
      animation-name: expandz;
      animation-duration: 1.5s; 
      animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
      animation-delay: 0;
      animation-direction: alternate;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-play-state: running;
    }
    
    @keyframes expandz {
      0% {
        transform: scale(.3);
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 100%;
      }
      50% {
        background-color: rgb(71, 8, 8);;
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        background-color: rgb(139, 139, 3);
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="btn4">
        <button class="btn4a" onclick="hiddenjs()">List of Other Games I'm going to review!</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="hiddenjs" class="hiddenjsa">
        Note: These are NOT clickable links yet as I have yet to review them and add them to the site. 
        These are just references to which I am in the process of reviewing!
    </div>
```

I was wondering, without jQuery, or any other forms of language if there is a way through JavaScript alone, that you can do a toggle button to do the animation (which I've done) and when you click said button again, it does the animation but in reverse?

I've read up a few things on it but can't find something without copy and pasting a jQuery snippet, and I don't want to do that because I want to understand what I'm doing.

Comment: No, it is not possible, but you can create another keyframe, and reverse the steps from there? Then, you decide what animation to launch at which moment.

Comment: How would I put that together with a button click to 'close' the show/hide button i'm doing?

Comment: Use transitions instead. They are best suited for this type of stuff only.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an animation on each click to either expand or reverse the expansion. Instead of display settings, set the scale at the start of the forward animation as 0.

This snippet deliberately has two keyframes which are identical but one set to run in reverse, just to make it clearer what is going on.

```js
function hiddenjs() {
     var x = document.getElementById("hiddenjs");
     if ( x.style.animationDirection != "normal" ) {
x.style.animationDirection = "normal";
x.style.animationName = "expandz";
}
      else {
x.style.animationDirection = "reverse";
x.style.animationName= "expandz1";
   
   }
}
```

```css
   .hiddenjsa {
      margin: 0 auto;
      transform: scale(0);
      background-color: red;
      animation-duration: 1.5s; 
      animation-timing-function: ease-out; 
      animation-delay: 0;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes expandz {
      0% { transform: scale(0); }
      1% {
        transform: scale(.3);
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 100%;
      }
      50% {
        background-color: rgb(71, 8, 8);;
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        background-color: rgb(139, 139, 3);
      }
    }
@keyframes expandz1 {
0% { transform: scale(0); }
  1% {
    transform: scale(.3);
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: rgb(71, 8, 8);;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    background-color: rgb(139, 139, 3);
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="btn4" style=“z-index:100;”>
        <button class="btn4a" onclick="hiddenjs()">List of Other Games I'm going to review!</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="hiddenjs" class="hiddenjsa">
        Note: These are NOT clickable links yet as I have yet to review them and add them to the site. 
        These are just references to which I am in the process of reviewing!
    </div>
```

Comment: Okay, so it's just like a normal "If" statement? That sums it up really good for me. Sorry about a easy question of JavaScript. I'm still learning. :D

Also, when I try this, it gets rid of the animation all together, so when I click my button, nothing shows up. 

I also have this code as a JS function:

      function hiddenjs() {
        var x = document.getElementById("hiddenjs");
        if (x.style.display === "block") {
          x.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          x.style.display = "block";
        }
      }

Comment: I think you need to get rid of that code - we've replaced it with making the hiddenjs div scale(0) and scale(1.5) - CSS animation doesn't let you animate display:none and so on, but it does let you animate scale.